# Access files in Torch iOS

Tags: ios, lua, torch

I have an image file and I want to access it in my Lua file. I already put the file in the project folder. However the call

local path = system.pathForFile("xxx", system.DocumentsDirectory) fails to work.

How should I do it?

Comment: How does it fail to work?

Comment: It stops at that line. Please keep in mind that I'm running it on Xcode.